# Order by european date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm busy with creating a message system for users. But I've some trouble with the european date format.

In my MySQL DB I've the date's stored like this :

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

For examle 07-04-2014 22:03:41 and 08-04-2014 19:32:23

But when I tried to order them by using `ORDER BY received DESC` (which works fine with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` it doesn't show the messages in the right order.

For example it shows 22-03-2014 as first and 08-04-2014 as latest.

Could someone help me out?

I've already tried `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` but that isn't working.

EDIT : 
Here's my Query btw;

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ID_receiver='$KlantID' AND ticket_nummer='$Ticket_Nmr' ORDER BY `received` DESC");
```

Comment: What is the exact column type in your DB? datetime?, timestamp?, etc.

Comment: I haven't set any column type because if I did that, there's no way to set date to d-m-Y only Y-m-d for so far I know

Comment: You should store datetime values in datetime columns. And don't order by computed values.

Comment: do you mean that the column is currently stored as a `varchar`?!

Comment: @user3366162: please use parameter with your prepared statement and bind the input values.

Comment: Yes, because I couldn't find any other solution to store the date in d-m-Y format by using `timestamp` or `datetime`. Or you guys have to know something/show me a post of it?

Comment: You can use STR_TO_DATE() with the right format-String, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date. BTW this format string would be 'd-m-Y H:i:s'. It's that easy ...

Comment: You don't store the date in 'd-m-Y' format; you store the date in one of MySQL's date/time datatypes, which accept their input and format their output as 'Y-m-d'... for input purposes, you convert your 'd-m-Y' to 'Y-m-d' before saving, and for output you convert it from 'Y-m-d' to 'd-m-Y' using PHP's date formatting functions.... but this allows MySQL to handle easy date comparisons and sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the date on the fly

```
 ...ORDER BY str_to_date(received, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

but this sounds like a rather bad idea to me. Why not to store dates in the native format, `DATETIME`?

Comment: how right you are. Some time later @user3366162 will complain about bad performance ...